# Firestore Import Error When In Jest With Next.JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, next.js, jestjs

I am trying to run a test in next.js using jest that imports firebase, but i keep getting an error:
`{import { registerVersion } from '@firebase/app'; SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module`

Importing other modules works, but firebase throughs that error. I have tried other enviroments but none seem to work and either throw this error or another error.

Package.JSON:

```
{
  "name": "chat",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "next dev",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "next start",
    "lint": "next lint",
    "test": "jest --forceExit --watchAll --coverage"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@firebase/testing": "^0.20.11",
    "firebase": "^9.9.4",
    "kill-port": "^2.0.1",
    "next": "12.2.5",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "18.2.0",
    "react-firebase-hooks": "^5.0.3",
    "react-hot-toast": "^2.3.0",
    "uuid": "^8.3.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/plugin-syntax-jsx": "^7.18.6",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.18.6",
    "@firebase/rules-unit-testing": "^2.0.4",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.5",
    "@testing-library/react": "^13.4.0",
    "@types/jest": "^29.0.2",
    "eslint": "8.23.0",
    "eslint-config-next": "12.2.5",
    "firebase-admin": "^11.0.1",
    "jest": "^29.0.3",
    "jest-environment-jsdom": "^29.0.3"
  }
}
```

Jest.config.js:

```
// jest.config.js
const nextJest = require('next/jest');

const createJestConfig = nextJest({
    // Provide the path to your Next.js app to load next.config.js and .env files in your test environment
    dir: './',
});

// Add any custom config to be passed to Jest
/** @type {import('jest').Config} */
const customJestConfig = {
    // Add more setup options before each test is run
    // setupFilesAfterEnv: ['<rootDir>/jest.setup.js'],
    // if using TypeScript with a baseUrl set to the root directory then you need the below for alias' to work
    //moduleDirectories: ['node_modules', '<rootDir>/'],
    testEnvironment: 'jest-environment-jsdom',
};

// createJestConfig is exported this way to ensure that next/jest can load the Next.js config which is async
module.exports = createJestConfig(customJestConfig);
```

test/page.test.js

```
 /**
 * @jest-environment jest-environment-jsdom
 */

import React from 'react';
import { render, screen } from '@testing-library/react';
import Thing from '../../pages/thing.jsx';

describe('testing Home page', () => {
    test('render h1 element', () => {
        expect(render(<Thing />));
    });
});
```

pages/test.jsx

```
import { firestore } from "../lib/firebase";

export default function Thing({ }) {
    return (
        <main>
        </main>
    );
}
```

lib/firebase (Note: removed config fields)

```
import { initializeApp } from 'firebase/app';
import { getAuth, GoogleAuthProvider } from 'firebase/auth';
import { getFirestore } from 'firebase/firestore';
import { getStorage } from 'firebase/storage';

const firebaseConfig = {
    apiKey: "",
    authDomain: "",
    projectId: "",
    storageBucket: "",
    messagingSenderId: "",
    appId: "",
    measurementId: ""
};

const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);


export const auth = getAuth(app);
export const googleAuthProvider = new GoogleAuthProvider();
export const firestore = getFirestore(app);
export const storage = getStorage(app);
```

Comment: I am also facing the same issue after upgrading the jest.
can pls try moduleNameMapper: ['^firebase/firestore/$': require.resolve('firebase/firestore')], add other firebase dependency too inside the module mapper

Comment: Refer this GitHub url: https://github.com/microsoft/accessibility-insights-web/pull/5421#issuecomment-1109168149

Comment: try this one also if the above doesn’t work https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/36682